# how to display sidebar in both left side bar and right side bar in 3 columns page layout on category page magento 2

Tags: magento2, category-listing

I select **3 columns** page layout on a category listing page.

It shows sidebar in left side but it does not show sidebar on right side.

How to show sidebar in both sides?

Comment: please let me know if any issue

Answer (score 0):

you have to override 3columns.xml file and keep below code,

file path: `app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Theme/page_layout/3columns.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="2columns-left"/>
    <update handle="2columns-right"/>
</layout>
```

Comment: I am new in magento. please tell me in detail.

Comment: have you create theme? if not create theme ,you need to refer first create theme in magento 2, http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Comment: I created a custom theme

Comment: inside your theme set inside this path 3columns.xml file, Magento_Theme/page_layout/3columns.xml,  Inside theme create Magento_Theme folder and inside this folder create page_layout folder

Comment: I have already Magento_Theme folder in my theme this folder contains layout and web folder and i created a page_layout folder

Comment: You are at right direction, Now inside page_layout folder keep 3columns.xml file with above code.

Comment: i put above code in 3columns.xml file

Comment: now clear cache and check in frontend

Comment: not working. there is no change on front end.

Comment: show your full code of 3 columns.xml in above questions

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="2columns-left"/>
    <update handle="2columns-right"/>
</layout>

Comment: have you clear cache and remove var folder from root?

Comment: yes, i cleared cache

Comment: but i did not remove var folder

Comment: try with remove folder and check

Comment: I removed var folder, and cleared cache but not working.

Comment: Why is it only referencing 2columns-left? Can you please provide an example how to use 3columns?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem, I choose 3 column layout for category and only left side category bar was showing. It is main sidebar, I checked in layout there is additional sidebar also. It will not show unless you add data in it. I added some test block and it starts showing. category_right_sidebar is static block and i added this code

```
 <referenceContainer name="div.sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="category_right_sidebar">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">category_right_sidebar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
 </referenceContainer>
```